# How can you pass a Blaze Template to the Column Title in Aldeed:Tabular?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, aldeed-tabular

In the column I'm displaying  YES/NO values as red/green Fontawsome icons. I'd like the column heading to also be the same icon, and not text work.

The aldeed:tabular allows Blaze templates to be passed when displaying a cells contents.... but is there a setting to pass Blaze template to the column title.

For cells the syntax is

```
{ 
  tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.blazeTemplateName
}
```

but for the **title** setting it doesn't seem to handle templates..the docs only have an example with a string
   { title: 'columnNameToDisplay' }

And when you try setting the title to a blaze template you get

```
TypeError: col.sTitle.replace is not a function
```

which clearly means its expecting text and not a template.

Any ideas how to also change the title display to a blaze template.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....you can pass HTML to the title.

```
{
 title: '<i class="fa fa-globe fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
}
```